# Power analysis of linear regression when one of the causal variables is missing

Tags: regression, statistical-power

Suppose we have two linear models:

\begin{align}
    y &= \beta_0 + \beta_1 A + \beta_2 B  + \epsilon & (1)\\
    y &= \beta_0 + \beta_1 A  + \epsilon & (2)
\end{align}

in which $A $ and $B$ are independent variables
uncorrelated to each other (i.e. zero collinearity).
I suspect that model 1 will always be more powerful
than model 2, since model 1 is equivalent to 
creating two models and doing two tests:

\begin{align}
    y &\sim A & (3)\\
    \text{Resid}(y \sim A) &\sim B & (4)
\end{align}

where model 3 is the same as model 2, and
an extra test gives you extra power. **But how much more power do we gain exactly?**